# react native: app disappears after reboot phone

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I develop little since with React Native.

I tried to install the APK generated from my application on an Android phone, which works perfectly well. But as soon as I restart the phone, the application that I installed disappears.

It looks like it's automatically uninstalled from the phone.
I use Visual Studio code as the development environment.
That's the problem I encountered.
So, I need your help.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53zkBvL4ZB4

Comment: can you post your manifest?